# What does the notation $^1 S_0$ represent in particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, notation, term-symbols

I'm coming across the notation $^1 S_0$, $^3 P_1$, $^1D_2$ etc. in relation to particle states. What do the two numbers and the letter represent? I've tried googling to no avail and it just appears in the lecture notes with no explanation.

It's probably really basic but not understanding what it represents is really slowing me down. Cheers.

Comment: This is a notation for atomic orbitals regarding the spin and orbital angular momentum. See e.g.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol

Comment: Do you actually mean particle physics? That term is generally reserved for things the size of a nucleus or smaller, whilst term symbols seem much more likely to be encountered in atomic physics for multi-electron atoms. (Of course nuclear physicists probably use the same/similar notation but I don't know about that.)

Comment: @jacob1729 it's in a particle physics module. Toffomat was correct, the upper left number is 2s+1 where s is the spin. The bottom left is the angular momentum. In my case it was being used in proton anti-proton decays to give information about the spin and angular momentum of the system. So while it can be used for atomic orbitals I'm guessing it can also be used in particle physics.

Comment: @Toffomat That was it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [**term symbols**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol), which are a compact way to encode the angular-momentum characteristics of a quantum state.

The general scheme for this notation is of the form ${}^{2S+1}L_J$, where:

- $2S+1$ is the spin multiplicity, i.e., the number of linearly-independent spin states of the system.
- $L$ is the total orbital angular momentum of the system, denoted in [spectroscopic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectroscopic_notation) (so the values $L=0,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$ are notated $S,P,D,F,G,H,\ldots$).
- $J$ is the total angular momentum of the system, obtained by combining the total spin and total orbital angular momentum quantum numbers, $S$ and $J$, using the quantum-mechanical [procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients) for the addition of angular momenta.

The fact that the quantum numbers are upper-case ($S,L,J$, as well as the upper-case letters $S,P,D,\ldots$ in the spectroscopic notation) indicates that they denote the total values of a multi-particle state. For single-particle quantities the usual convention is to use lower-case letters and symbols.

It's probably fair to say that term symbols are most commonly used in atomic physics, and there they represent the various angular momenta of the electrons in the system. However, the notation is generic, and it can also be applied to particle-physics contexts, and there they could be used to denote some specific scattering state, as well as, say, the way in which the angular momenta of a set of quarks combine to make a bound state (that we then call a particle). The specific details of exactly *which* angular momenta are being referred to will, of course, depend on the context where the term symbol appears.

Comment: Thank you very much, really useful answer! I was unsure what S,P,D,F would represent in a particle physics context but I see from your answer that they represent the total orbital angular momentum of the system.

Comment: A common non-atomic example arises in discussions of the different lifetimes of ortho-positronium ($^3S_1$) versus para-positronium ($^1S_0$). In atomic physics the spin-orbit coupling is weak and $S,L,J$ may all three be good quantum numbers, but in nuclear and particle physics that assumption may be invalid, so term symbols are less useful there. For instance, in the deuteron ($J^P=1^+$) spin is a good quantum number for reasons of exchange symmetry, but $L$ is constrained only by the parity; the deuteron ground state is mostly $^3S_1$ but about 4% is $^3D_1$.